# Paramiko on HP Provision

Tags: python, networking, paramiko, switching, aruba

Please help, there is a problem when executing a script on Paramiko, when displaying information from the switch.Aruba 2530,OS Provision

Script:

```
import paramiko
import getpass
import time
import json

with open('devices.json', 'r') as f:
devices = json.load(f)
with open ('commands.txt', 'r') as f:
commands = [line for line in f.readlines()]

username = input('Username: ')
password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
max_buffer = 65535

def clear_buffer(connection):
if connection.recv_ready():
    return connection.recv(max_buffer)

# Starts the loop for devices
for device in devices.keys(): 
outputFileName = device + '_output.txt'
connection = paramiko.SSHClient()
connection.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
connection.connect(devices[device]['ip'], username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
new_connection = connection.invoke_shell()
output = clear_buffer(new_connection)
time.sleep(3)
#new_connection.send("terminal length 5\n")
output = clear_buffer(new_connection)
with open(outputFileName, 'wb') as f:
    for command in commands:
        new_connection.send(command)
        time.sleep(2)
        output = new_connection.recv(max_buffer)
        print(output)
        f.write(output)
print ("\r\nEXIT"*15)        
new_connection.close()
```

After execution produces the following:
[Incomprehensible thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RubM.png)

In the output.txt I have:

[output.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpeJW.png)

In Comware all fine.I know python at a basic level, I don’t understand what this can mean.

Comment: Could you add the incomprehensible thing and the output as formatted text in your question please, rather than as images. Thanks.

Comment: @mrblewog
ok

 **'b'\x1b[24;11Hshow run v\x1b[24;11H\x1b[?25h\x1b[24;21H\x1b[24;21Hlan 
| inc \x1b[24;21H\x1b[?25h\x1b[24;31H\x1b[24;31H10.125\x1b
[24;31H\x1b[?25h\x1b[24;37H\x1b[1;0H\x1b[1M\x1b[24;1H\x1b
[1L\x1b[24;37H\x1b[24;1H\x1b[2K\x1b[24;1H\x1b[?25h\x1b[24;1H
\x1b[1;24r\x1b[24;1H\x1b[1;24r\x1b[24;1H\x1b[24;1H\x1b
[?25h\x1b[24;1H\x1b[24;1H\r\r\n\x1b[?25h\x1b[24;1H\x1b**


It's part of output in cmd,but others is the same.
output in output.txt:

 **[24;11Hshow run v[24;11H[?25h[24;21H[24;21Hlan **

Commands.txt:
show run vlan | inc 10.125
show mac-address | inc 64f0
exit

Answer (score 0):

```
import paramiko
import getpass
import time
import json
import re

with open('devices.json', 'r') as f:
    devices = json.load(f)
with open ('commands.txt', 'r') as f:
    commands = [line for line in f.readlines()]

username = input('Username: ')
password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
max_buffer = 65535

def escape_ansi(line):
    ansi_escape = re.compile(r'(?:\x1B[@-_]|[\x80-\x9F])[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')
    return ansi_escape.sub('', line)

def clear_buffer(connection):
    if connection.recv_ready():
        return connection.recv(max_buffer)

# Starts the loop for devices
for device in devices.keys(): 
    outputFileName = device + '_output.txt'
    connection = paramiko.SSHClient()
    connection.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    connection.connect(devices[device]['ip'], username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
    new_connection = connection.invoke_shell()
    output = clear_buffer(new_connection)
    time.sleep(3)
    #new_connection.send("terminal length 5\n")
    output = clear_buffer(new_connection).decode('utf-8') # #first decode,then kill ANSI-symbols,for output
    a=escape_ansi(output)
    print (a)
    with open(outputFileName, 'wb') as f:
        for command in commands:
            new_connection.send(command)
            time.sleep(2)
            output = new_connection.recv(max_buffer)
            b=output.decode('utf-8') #first decode,then kill ANSI-symbols,for output to terminal
            b=escape_ansi(b)
            print(b)
            c = b.encode('utf-8') #encode from str to bytes,for write to file.
            f.write(c)
    print ("\r\nEXIT"*15)        
    new_connection.close()
```